# JGit vs GitHub & GitLab Rest apis

Tags: git, github, gitlab, bitbucket, jgit

This is kind of R&D question.
As per my understanding, JGit provides the java implementation of git behaviors and is, therefore, platform agnostic.
Github and Gitlab both have their respective Rest API endpoints that we can configure in an application.

My requirement is to show, push and commit some files from my application on to Github repos. In future I might have to support gitlab as well.

As per my understanding I should use the Jgit instead of individual rest apis so that same implementation will be used for any git platform. We just be updating configurable settings in our app to reference wither Github or Gitlab.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track.

Comment: The APIs you mention are not REST APIs: the Git APIs that JGit needs to implement have to do with exchanging commits using `git push` and `git fetch` protocols. These are ad-hoc and not RESTful at all. (This doesn't affect your decision here, it's just something to know.)